# Android - Loading image fail

Tags: android

I am trying to load image like in this link,- it doesn't work, only black screen. Why? I tried in emulators with Android 1.5 and 2.2.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-load-image-from-url-example/

**UPDATE:** I solve my problem, I should add `INTERNET to "uses-permission"` before `application` tag, but I did after it

Comment: have you added INTERNET to "uses-permission"? Does you device or emulator has some internet connection? do you see something in logs?

Comment: yes i added INTERNET to "uses-permission", from default browser in emulator i can enter in INTERNET, logs too doesn't show anything bad.It's very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add INTERNET to "uses-permission" before application tag